# Using DirectX(SharpDX) what is the best way to create a single large image from smaller images?

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

I'm looking for the best way to combine several images (1060 x 1060)each into on large image. I'm looking to create one texture to apply to a single Quad. I was thinking multiple quads and then just use a Shader in 3D. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get this to work correctly. I have 16 quads in a 4 x 4 arrangement. However, I can only see 4 of 16. I'm trying to get the 16 to fit like a single quad would without a camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your goal is to create a mega bitmap, why don't you do it programatically and write all of it into 1 target bitmap.

Create a 4 x 4 array, for  each row, read each line and write them 1 after the other sequentially.  Ala, texture 1, line 1, texture 2 line 1 etc.  I think that will give you a more lossless version of the bitmap without any issues with seaming etc.

You are basically limited to the amount of physical memory on your pc (unless really silly size).

I assume these are bitmaps assume 32bit, you are only creating a 90MB file or so.

Ie, 1060 x 1060 is approx 4.5mb file

Comment: 34,992 x 34,992 x 32bit, it is a very high res set of images. Thanks.